# SQLAlchemy: Difference between joinedload and subqueryload behavior

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

I found a surprising difference between SQLAlchemy's [joinedload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload), and [subqueryload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload), specifically with how they handle [with_polymorphic](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance_loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_polymorphic). When using `subqueryload`, I am not able to eagerly load a relationship on a subclass of the relationship included in the `subqueryload`, whereas `joinedload` seems to handle this just fine.

For example, say I have a `User` class that has-many `Shape` objects. A `Rectangle` is a shape, and say it has-a `Widget` related to it. When querying the `User` class, I'd like to be able to construct my query options so all of the user's rectangle's widgets will be eagerly fetched, and I'd like to query the shapes as a subquery (rather than a joined load) to reduce the amount of duplicated data in the returned result set. I can get it working by join loading the `shapes` relationship, but I can't get it working as a subquery. Any thoughts?

Example, in code:

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    backref,
    joinedload,
    relationship,
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    subqueryload,
    with_polymorphic)
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey,
    MetaData,
    String)


logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Shape(Base):
    __tablename__ = "shapes"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": "type"}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    owner = relationship("User", backref=backref("shapes"), cascade="all")


class Rectangle(Shape):
    __tablename__ = "shapes_rectangles"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "RECT"}

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("shapes.id"), primary_key=True)
    length = Column(Integer)
    width = Column(Integer)
    widget_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("widgets.id"))
    widget = relationship("Widget", cascade="all")


class Widget(Base):
    __tablename__ = "widgets"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
with engine.begin() as connection:
    metadata = Base.metadata
    metadata.create_all(connection)

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

user = User()
widget = Widget()
rectangle = Rectangle(owner=user, widget=widget, length=10, width=5)
session.add_all([user, widget, rectangle])
session.commit()

shapes_load = subqueryload(
    User.shapes.of_type(
        with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True)))

session.remove()
query = session.query(User) .options(shapes_load.joinedload(Rectangle.widget))
logger.info("##########subqueryload begin")
user = query.one()
logger.info("##########accessing widget")
user.shapes[0].widget
logger.info("##########subqueryload end")

shapes_load = joinedload(
    User.shapes.of_type(
        with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True)))

session.remove()
query = session.query(User).options(shapes_load.joinedload(Rectangle.widget))
logger.info("##########joinedload begin")
user = query.one()
logger.info("##########accessing widget")
user.shapes[0].widget
logger.info("##########joinedload end")
```

Relevant output:

```
INFO:__main__:##########subqueryload begin
2017-12-19 23:03:36,826 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2017-12-19 23:03:36,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id
FROM users
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT users.id AS users_id
FROM users
2017-12-19 23:03:36,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
2017-12-19 23:03:36,829 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT anon_1.shapes_id AS anon_1_shapes_id, anon_1.shapes_type AS anon_1_shapes_type, anon_1.shapes_owner_id AS anon
_1_shapes_owner_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_length AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_length, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_wid
th AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_width, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_widget_id, anon_2.users_id AS anon_2_users_id
FROM (SELECT users.id AS users_id
FROM users) AS anon_2 JOIN (SELECT shapes.id AS shapes_id, shapes.type AS shapes_type, shapes.owner_id AS shapes_owner_id, shapes_rectangles.id AS shapes_rectangles_id, shapes_
rectangles.length AS shapes_rectangles_length, shapes_rectangles.width AS shapes_rectangles_width, shapes_rectangles.widget_id AS shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM shapes LEFT OUTER JOIN shapes_rectangles ON shapes.id = shapes_rectangles.id) AS anon_1 ON anon_2.users_id = anon_1.shapes_owner_id ORDER BY anon_2.users_id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT anon_1.shapes_id AS anon_1_shapes_id, anon_1.shapes_type AS anon_1_shapes_type, anon_1.shapes_owner_id AS anon_1_shapes_owner_id, anon
_1.shapes_rectangles_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_length AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_length, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_width AS anon_1_shapes_rect
angles_width, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_widget_id, anon_2.users_id AS anon_2_users_id
FROM (SELECT users.id AS users_id
FROM users) AS anon_2 JOIN (SELECT shapes.id AS shapes_id, shapes.type AS shapes_type, shapes.owner_id AS shapes_owner_id, shapes_rectangles.id AS shapes_rectangles_id, shapes_
rectangles.length AS shapes_rectangles_length, shapes_rectangles.width AS shapes_rectangles_width, shapes_rectangles.widget_id AS shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM shapes LEFT OUTER JOIN shapes_rectangles ON shapes.id = shapes_rectangles.id) AS anon_1 ON anon_2.users_id = anon_1.shapes_owner_id ORDER BY anon_2.users_id
2017-12-19 23:03:36,829 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
INFO:__main__:##########accessing widget
2017-12-19 23:03:36,831 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT widgets.id AS widgets_id
FROM widgets
WHERE widgets.id = ?
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT widgets.id AS widgets_id
FROM widgets
WHERE widgets.id = ?
2017-12-19 23:03:36,831 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(1,)
INFO:__main__:##########subqueryload end
2017-12-19 23:03:36,832 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:ROLLBACK
INFO:__main__:##########joinedload begin
2017-12-19 23:03:36,837 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2017-12-19 23:03:36,838 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, anon_1.shapes_id AS anon_1_shapes_id, anon_1.shapes_type AS anon_1_shapes_type, anon_1.s
hapes_owner_id AS anon_1_shapes_owner_id, widgets_1.id AS widgets_1_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_length AS anon_1_sh
apes_rectangles_length, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_width AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_width, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT shapes.id AS shapes_id, shapes.type AS shapes_type, shapes.owner_id AS shapes_owner_id, shapes_rectangles.id AS shapes_rectangles_id, shapes_
rectangles.length AS shapes_rectangles_length, shapes_rectangles.width AS shapes_rectangles_width, shapes_rectangles.widget_id AS shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM shapes LEFT OUTER JOIN shapes_rectangles ON shapes.id = shapes_rectangles.id) AS anon_1 ON users.id = anon_1.shapes_owner_id LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets AS widgets_1 ON widget
s_1.id = anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT users.id AS users_id, anon_1.shapes_id AS anon_1_shapes_id, anon_1.shapes_type AS anon_1_shapes_type, anon_1.shapes_owner_id AS anon_1
_shapes_owner_id, widgets_1.id AS widgets_1_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_id, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_length AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_length,
anon_1.shapes_rectangles_width AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_width, anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id AS anon_1_shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT shapes.id AS shapes_id, shapes.type AS shapes_type, shapes.owner_id AS shapes_owner_id, shapes_rectangles.id AS shapes_rectangles_id, shapes_
rectangles.length AS shapes_rectangles_length, shapes_rectangles.width AS shapes_rectangles_width, shapes_rectangles.widget_id AS shapes_rectangles_widget_id
FROM shapes LEFT OUTER JOIN shapes_rectangles ON shapes.id = shapes_rectangles.id) AS anon_1 ON users.id = anon_1.shapes_owner_id LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets AS widgets_1 ON widget
s_1.id = anon_1.shapes_rectangles_widget_id
2017-12-19 23:03:36,839 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
INFO:__main__:##########accessing widget
INFO:__main__:##########joinedload end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a bug with how I was using `with_polymorphic`. This patch [1] fixes the `subqueryload` query, so it does *not* emit a query when accessing `user.shapes[0].widget` (which is the expected behavior).

In SQLAlchemy version 1.3, the original test case fails with an exception like:

```
ArgumentError: Attribute "Rectangle.widget" does not link from element "with_polymorphic(Shape, [])".
```

[1]

```
@@ -72,12 +72,13 @@ rectangle = Rectangle(owner=user, widget=widget, length=10, width=5)
 session.add_all([user, widget, rectangle])
 session.commit()

-shapes_load = subqueryload(
-    User.shapes.of_type(
-        with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True)))
+polymorphic_shape = with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True)
+shapes_load = subqueryload(User.shapes.of_type(polymorphic_shape))

 session.remove()
-query = session.query(User) .options(shapes_load.joinedload(Rectangle.widget))
+query = session.query(User).options(
+    shapes_load.joinedload(polymorphic_shape.Rectangle.widget)
+)
 logger.info("##########subqueryload begin")
 user = query.one()
 logger.info("##########accessing widget")
@@ -85,11 +86,13 @@ user.shapes[0].widget
 logger.info("##########subqueryload end")

 shapes_load = joinedload(
-    User.shapes.of_type(
-        with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True)))
+    User.shapes.of_type(with_polymorphic(Shape, "*", aliased=True))
+)

 session.remove()
-query = session.query(User).options(shapes_load.joinedload(Rectangle.widget))
+query = session.query(User).options(
+    shapes_load.joinedload(polymorphic_shape.Rectangle.widget)
+)
 logger.info("##########joinedload begin")
 user = query.one()
 logger.info("##########accessing widget")
```